# In Spring State Machine Papyrus UML, how to move from any of the multiple states to Canceled state, based on specific event?

Tags: uml, spring-statemachine, papyrus

There is 20 states and I want to move from any of that state to Canceled state, based on specific event. How can I achieve this using Papyrus UML Spring State Machine?

I'm expecting like a grouping of multiple states and connect this group to the canceled state.

Comment: How about creating a sub-state?

Comment: @thomas: I guess you meant to suggest that these states would all be substates of some common state that has a common transition.

Comment: @JimL. Yes. I'm no expert with SMs but it just feels like there should be a sub-state being modeled.

Comment: The OP owes us at least an attempt at a SM to reason about.

Comment: @Thomas I'll try it out and let you know